# mingw-4.8.1 atomic issue

Tags: c++11, mingw, atomic

I've the following compile error when I try to use the method is_lock_free() of atomic.

```
struct Simple1 { int i; };
struct Simple2 { int a; int b; };
struct Simple3 { int a; int b; int c; };

int main()
{
    atomic< Counter > counter;
    atomic< Param > param;
    atomic< Simple1 > s1;
    atomic< Simple2 > s2;
    atomic< Simple3 > s3;

    cout
        << "Is s1 lock free? " << boolalpha << s1.is_lock_free() << '\n'
        << "Is s2 lock free? " << boolalpha << s2.is_lock_free() << '\n'
        << "Is s3 lock free? " << boolalpha << s3.is_lock_free() << '\n';
   }
```

`s1.is_lock_free() and s2.is_lock_free()` are okay and `atomic< builtin >::is_lock_free()`, where `builtin` is a fondamental type, works well.

But for s3 the call of `is_lock_free` gives a linkage error: `undefined reference to __atomic_is_lock_free`

Does I need to link some external library? What can I do?

**Edit 1**

The same issue occur on gcc4.8.1 on Ubuntu 13.04

The comand line option is the following:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -o "atomic_test.o" "atomic_test.cpp" 
g++ -std=c++11 -o hello.exe atomic_test.o
```

**Edit 2**

I added -latomic and -lpthread on gcc but I've the same error:

```
04:09:37: Running steps for project atomic...
04:09:37: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
04:09:37: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/home/dmdtek/Qt/5.1.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug      CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ../atomic/atomic.pro
g++ -latomic -lpthread -Wl,-rpath,/home/dmdtek/Qt/5.1.0/gcc_64 -o atomic main.o    
main.o: In function `std::atomic<Simple3>::is_lock_free() const':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/atomic:191: undefined reference to `__atomic_is_lock_free'
main.o: In function `std::atomic<long double>::is_lock_free() const':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/atomic:191: undefined reference to `__atomic_is_lock_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [atomic] Error 1
04:09:37: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project atomic (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.0 GCC 64bit)
When executing step 'Make'
04:09:37: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

libatomic is present on my system:

```
$ ldconfig -v | grep atomic
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
libatomic.so.1 -> libatomic.so.1.0.0
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to link with `libatomic` (which is provided by GCC):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o hello.exe atomic_test.o -latomic
```

Comment: It may be my fault: try moving the `-latomic` before the `.o` on the command line and let me know if it works so that I can update my answer.

Comment: no same result: `g++ -c -pipe -std=c++11 -lpthread -g -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -I../../../../Qt/5.1.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../atomic -I. -o main.o ../atomic/main.cpp`
`g++ -latomic -lpthread -Wl,-rpath,/home/dmdtek/Qt/5.1.0/gcc_64 -o atomic main.o    `

Comment: I'm using qtcreator 2.8 on ubuntu 13.04 with g++-4.8.1 ( downloaded via ppa ), but seems gcc the issue: MinGW-4.8.1 gives same result.

Comment: Well on my machine (Debian Jessie / GCC 4.8.1) `-latomic` is enough to correctly link your code (whether at the beginning or at the end of the linking command, it doesn't change anything after all) so GCC itself is not at fault (maybe the build you installed from the PPA has a problem, though). I'm afraid I can't really help more than that.