# MinGW GCC 4.8.0 on Windows doesn't support atomic features

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++, atomic

```
#include <atomic>

struct SomeType
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};

int main()
{
    SomeType s1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::atomic<SomeType> s2(s1);

    SomeType s3 = s2.load();

    return 0;
}
```

The code doesn't link using `gcc version 4.8.0 (rev2, Built by MinGW-builds project)` with `gcc -std=c++11 t.cpp`. Error messages are:

```
ccGPZTVk.o:t.cpp(.text$_ZNKSt6atomicI8SomeTypeE4loadESt12memory_order[__ZNKSt6atomicI8SomeTypeE4loadESt12memory_order]+0x21): undefined reference to `__atomic_load_16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

According to C++11 standard, types like `SomeType` which is trivially copyable should definitely fit in a std::atomic...and MSVC `cl /EHsc t.cpp` works like a charm. Is this a bug of GCC? How can I solve this weird problem...

Comment: try to pass `-latomic` when compiling/linking .

Comment: Both `gcc t.cpp -std=c++11 -latomic` and `g++ t.cpp -std=c++11 -latomic` have no effect at all.

Comment: probably a problem with your `gcc` building or with the linker, you should specify your mingw version and the threading model adopted by your toolchain, mingw comes in different flavours.

Comment: It seems to be [duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697232/mingw-4-8-1-atomic-issue).

Comment: @wesley.mesquita I saw that post, but found that it is actually unsolved...

Comment: @Zizheng Tai I did not see any clues of this. I have a MINGW env with GCC 4.8.1. Same results. I tried all tips. Maybe the best solution for you is to use boost by now.

Comment: [Go get a newer MinGW release - MinGW-builds is up to 4.8.2 now, and all threading features work fine.](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php)

Comment: @Casey I get the latest MinGW with gcc 4.8.2, but the problem still exists. I have turned to boost for now.